# Wordpress template registration cuztomization

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to develop a wordpress intranet site using Alliance template. Are the template registration forms customizable, so that only users with company email id are allowed to register? is there any plugin for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

1. try to create a theme from scratch so there will be no issues ever
2. keep all css, js files in folder instead of using cdn
3. create accounts manually for company members, assign job role as subscriber
4. can use 'is admin' plugin or code to hide pages from non logged in users

can use this if new to wordpress coding https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-registration/